# i need to join two tables. first table have some data with id column and second table have data with same id but multiple id will be there

Tags: sql, sql-server

**table 1**

```
workid est_amt  amount_spent
1       1000     50
2       200     100
```

**table 2**

```
workid  totalDeduction  amt_payble
1        30              20 
1        30              20 
2        25              30
```

Code

```
select count(a.workid),a.est_amt,SUM(a.amt_spent + b.total_deductions + b.amt_payable) from table1 a left join table2 b on a.workid = b.workid
```

result should be

```
total_works amount_paid   balance_amount_to_pay
2            305          695
```

am getting this result

```
total_works amount_paid   balance_amount_to_pay
3            305          695
```

Answer (score 1):

using `distinct()` will get only the count of unique Ids.

```
select count(distinct a.workid)
    ,SUM(a.est_amt)
    ,SUM(a.amt_spent + b.total_deductions + b.amt_payable) 
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.workid = b.workid
```